# Can I Avoid Tupled Parameters In This Elixir Anonymous Function?

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

I'm working through "Programming Elixir" and I came across the exercise headed "Exercise: Functions 2".  Long story short, basically code a function which emits Fizzbuzz if the first two parameters are 0, Fizz if the first param is 0, Buzz if the second param is 0 and the third param if neither of the first two are zero.  I came up with this:

```
fizzbuzztest = fn
   {0,0,_} -> "FizzBuzz"
   {0,_,_} -> "Fizz"
   {_,0,_} -> "Buzz"
   {_,_,v} -> "#{v}"
end
```

Called like so:

```
fizzbuzztest.({0,0,8}) # "FizzBuzz"
```

But I'm wondering--is there some way to do this without having to tuple the parameters? It seems there should be some way to pass three arguments and work the pattern match but I haven't found it yet.  Any suggestions from those more experienced with Elixir would be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this particular exercise with:

```
fizzbuzztest = fn
   0,0,_ -> "FizzBuzz"
   0,_,_ -> "Fizz"
   _,0,_ -> "Buzz"
   _,_,v -> "#{v}"
end
```

Comment: Don't know why I assumed I'd need to tuple the parameters to get this to work.  Thanks.

Comment: The early examples of `fn` don't make it clear you can pattern match arguments like above.  Almost all are in the form 

`a = fn(arg1, argn) end`